# How can I add different layers from XML file using PYQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, xml

I have multiple xml files contains different layer. I want to write a script to find just layers that their name is street_name and city_name? How can I open these files in qgis console?

Comment: XML is merely an encoding for different data. You might want to specify what exactly your XML file is and what it contains so people can attempt to help you. E.g. Is it a GML file, a QGIS project xml file, an openstreetmap XML or some custom file of yours?

Comment: Could you share XML content?